# Jade mixin render not right

Tags: node.js, pug

I have this code:

```
each item in parent
    li.category
        button
            snap
        +link()
```

And its print this:

```
<li>
    <button>
        <snap></snap>
    </button>
</li>
**<div>**
```

and not inside the the "li" tag
What should I do?

Comment: Try to convert spaces to tabs and try again, can you show us your mixin code too

Comment: its already tabs. and the mixin code is the same. its recursive

Comment: I found what the problem:

Comment: each loop inside each loop not working

Comment: That's why i told you  to show us your mixin code, But Thanks for sharing the solution Too